# Passing comma separated .txt file to MYSQL command not allowed with MySQL version

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error when I run my script `update.sh`:

`ERROR 1148 (42000) at line 16: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

My MySQL version is: `Server version: 5.6.26 Homebrew`

I checked in the documentation and it allows for this command:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS rsAdmin;
USE rsAdmin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  hdfs_archive (
   inputpath        char(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,   
   policy       enum('ARCHIVE','DELETE','CONCATENATE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ARCHIVE', 
   retention        int NOT NULL DEFAULT 6,
   outputpath       char(255),
   user         char(32),
   status       varchar(512)
);

TRUNCATE TABLE hdfs_archive;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './archive_data.txt'
INTO TABLE hdfs_archive FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES ;
```

Line 16 is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './archive_data.txt'
```

My project structure is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see another section in the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data-local.html

> If LOAD DATA LOCAL is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:
>
> ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

If you are lucky, adding `--local-infile=1` will do the trick (depends on the server configuration).

Otherwise, the SQL script is OK (it worked for me).

Comment: tried this: `mysql --user="user" --password="pass" --local-infile=0 < archive_ddl.sql` but still got the same error =[

Comment: The page in the manual says: "In any case, successful use of a local load operation requires that the server permits it." Sorry, I am not more familiar with the topic, but I guess you need to look at the server configuration.

Comment: ... and it should be `--local-infile=1`. Edited my answer.